# Does buried cast iron have a coating?

Tags: plumbing, drain, cast-iron

After fully exposing the cast iron pipe that I will be working on, I noticed that it has a coating ... however the pipe looks in good shape underneath ... is this just corrosion or compacted dirt or some sort of special coating?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Looks like some kind of concrete/mortar encasement to me.